# If flags aren't for this, what are they for?

Tags: discussion, support, flags, declined-flags, not-an-answer

I recently flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63661438/how-do-i-fix-ispcbin-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/63661536#63661536) answer because it was a flippant response and not a real attempt to answer the question.

The flag was declined, with the explanation "they are not for flagging inaccurate or incorrect answers". If you can't flag a flippant, inaccurate, incorrect or generally unhelpful answer then what can you do about them and what are flags for?

Comment: You can flag for rudeness but the "Not an Answer" flag is for posts that aren't even trying to answer the question. For example, if someone posts an additional question as an answer to your question you could use the NAA flag for that. (I wouldn't use the Very Low Quality flag, apparently there's still disagreement about what it's for.)

Comment: You may want to read [When to flag an answer as “not an answer”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer), [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) and [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)

Comment: Wrong answers can't be deleted. I believe they get mass downvoted, and that's the most anyone can do.

Comment: FWIW, given that other user's recent meta post, I think you two were talking past each other.

Comment: Don't see how taking this aggressive approach helps your chances of getting a solution. Leaving civil comments like "this doesn't work because..." and letting the answer stand improves chances someone else might read that and provide an alternate solution building on what is in the first one

Comment: @charlie: OK, "This doesn't work because...", 1. There is no such directory. So his claim I can "easily spot" it in the directory structure is false. On the contrary, I can "easily spot" there is no such directory to find. If I were to spend the time it would take to find and change the line in the process to what he suggests then it would only throw exactly the same error again. 2. CMake is *not*, as he implied, a drop-in replacement for MSBuild. CMake and MSBuild do not do the same job. Therefore both his suggestions are guesswork and they are both incorrect.

Comment: @10Rep wrong answers can be deleted. When they are scored < 0 users with 20K of rep or more will delete vote such answers. The < 0 score rule does indeed require that not every visitor upvotes a wrong answer "because of their effort spend posting it"

Comment: @rene Well, I don't have that privilege, so forgive my ignorance.

Comment: @10Rep yeah, it is a long way. Worst is between 10K and 20K. You're then trusted to delete questions but can't touch answers....

Comment: *Your example is not an example of what he did.* @GeorginaDavenport It’s not supposed to be an example of what they did. You said at one point in the comments that opinionated answers are against the rules. That’s not true. I put the example in my reply to demonstrate why it’s not true. I was not arguing that the actual answer was correct or not rude. I was saying we can’t flag an answer just because it has an opinion in it.

Comment: @BSMP, very well but it seems paradoxical to me to disallow questions which seek POV answers but then accept POV answers. In either case an opinion-based answer was not sought and the description of MSBuild as "absolute crap" was vulgar, nonconstructive and surplus to requirements. In addition to that, as I have said previously, CMake is *not* merely a drop-in replacement for MSBuild, and in fact I was using CMake already as part of the same process, to generate MSBuild projects, which herein is a project requirement, for programmers using Visual Studio to develop applications for Windows.

Answer (score 19):

I declined the flag, and I did so because, to the untrained eye (read: me), *it looks like an answer*. This looks like a new user saying "This doesn't answer *my* question", especially in light of the snarky comments you traded with the poster

> You are doing nobody a favour if you don't really know what the answer is. Everybody supplies help for free here. It is no reason to post junk responses and waste everybody's time.

As Robert Harvey noted, a mod flag would let you add some context as to what you think the problem is. If it actually is flippant, it's not obvious, and being belligerent in comments won't help your case any.

Comment: If you hadn't noticed, that answer you've highlighted was in response to his, in which he, after I queried his response, gloated that he was "doing me a favour" and because he was answering my question "for free" and not paying him, I have no right to question him. Despite the fact his answer is incorrect. I notice you didn't quote him telling me to use CMake or calling MSBuild "absolute crap", despite the fact opinion-based answers are disallowed on SO. Not to mention, CMake is *not* a replacement for MSBuild.

Comment: What it "looks like" to me is a case of "Oh look, a girl, that means I don't have to respect them". What's your point here? It's ok for other users to be rude to me but I have to be polite to them?

Comment: I certainly didn't pay any attention to or assigned any significance to your gender until you pointed it out. I'm afraid you are being over-sensitive.

Comment: He talked about what "it looks like". My point is that is not "what it looks like" to me. Anyway, unless you're the same person speaking through an alt I was neither talking to you or about you. In fact I don't even know who you are. So who's being over sensitive?

Comment: *...opinion-based answers are disallowed on SO...* @GeorginaDavenport We don’t allow questions that ask for opinions but there isn’t an explicit rule against them in answers. If someone asked how to change the color of some text on hover using JavaScript and my answer included, “This is easier with CSS: [some code]” that might be considered helpful. In some cases it’s inappropriate but there isn’t a blanket rule.

Comment: @GeorginaDavenport For what its worth, the text from the user you mention here has been either deleted or edited out; those comments weren’t considered OK. Rudeness is against the rules.

Comment: @BSMP: Your example is not an example of what he did. If he'd said "This would be easier if you..." and followed it with an example I might have accepted it. He didn't do that, he just said "MSBuild is absolute crap, you should use CMake". Which apart from being nonconstructive is also, again, inaccurate. I used CMake, to make the MSBuild project. CMake is not an MSBuild replacement. So his answer was rude and no part of it is correct, or called for, which is why I posted this question asking why it isn't flaggable.

Comment: Incidentally, I also notice questions I asked four years ago have been voted down this morning, supposedly by people retaliating as a consequence of this discussion. How very grown up.

Comment: @GeorginaDavenport You're making some assumptions in the comments, that I think are a bit of a stretch. First it seems you're assuming the tone in the Answer on your post on main is based on your gender. Why would you make such an assumption? Second, you're assuming the gender of the answerer. Again, why are you making such assumption?

Comment: @Scratte: I don't think either of those points is particularly pertinent. You might also notice quite a lot of assumptions have been made about me.

Comment: @GeorginaDavenport You're right. It's completely irrelevant and unlikely to be the reason for the quality of the Answer, so I don't understand why you brought any of those aspects up. I do not see any assumptions being made by others about you in this post though.

Comment: @Georgina I mean..... Really take a step back and see how you react to ppl helping you? I'm not saying the downvotes are warranted. but there is a bit of an intense reaction on your side when ppl post. Machavity explained why he didn't action the flag, you jump on 'youre sexist'. Someone else comes in to explain why it may not be that... 'I wasn't talking to you, who are you?'. Can you... Maybe see how you're rubbing ppl the wrong way? Don't get me wrong. Doesn't justify drive by downvotes on your stuff... But being polite, calm and contained always provides better results :). Good luck!

Comment: LOL. No I didn't. It was simply a response to his remark "How it looks to me". It may surprise you but I am not in the least bit interested in having a discussion about gender. Although after making about 20 previous comments which said nothing about it, this seems have instantly become the popular topic. Perhaps you would like to remind me what comment you thought was helpful? As with others, your attitude appears to be "other people are allowed to make stupid remarks, and you aren't allowed to respond in kind".

Comment: @Georgina also known as 'two wrongs don't make a right'. Yes. In general, it serves your purpose better and doesn't make you look at odds with anyone. And btw, **you** jumped on the 'Im a girl and this makes me feel like you're sexist', so saying that gender is irrelevant is.... Kinda false. Anyway, sorry for trying to point out you attract more flies with honey than vinegar.... I'll keep to myself next time someone comes on meta to 'ask  a question' when in fact all they want is 'I have to be told I'm right or this is unacceptable'. Have a good day, and again. Good luck

Comment: @GeorginaDavenport If the answer is wrong then the clear action here is to downvote it and comment why it's wrong. I am by no means saying the poster's deleted comment was right, either, but the way it played out to me is the comments got heated so you flagged it NAA because it was, in your view, wrong. That relies wholly on a moderator or reviewers to know enough to both agree and delete, which is not how NAA works. Again, if you want to make the case that he's being unserious (and it's a weak one at that) mod flags are the way to go.

Comment: You admitted yourself you are unable to gauge the situation because you aren't familar with the software being discussed, so who are you to judge whether he was being serious or not? Having read his original response, saying "MSBuild is crap", and "You can clearly see if you look at the directory tree" and ending up with essentially telling me to look through the build scripts and edit them myself, even though he clearly doesn't really have any idea what the fault is. What's the part of that which you take seriously?

Comment: Because you flagged it **Not an Answer**. That's something we deal with hundreds of times a day. If you want a quality judgment, that's not what NAA is for, because we tend to err on the side of keeping things that look like answers. I call it an attempt at an answer because it **ostensibly suggests something to try**. Whether or not that suggestion is useful is something for downvotes.

Comment: We clearly have different ideas about what "looks like" an answer. What it looks like to me is a flippant snarky response from somebody who doesn't understand the problem, hasn't thought about it, hasn't encountered or solved the same problem before and hasn't proposed a workable solution. What he claimed was "clearly" so, is clearly not so. There isn't any point in "trying" to change the project files to point at a directory which doesn't exist. It will only generate exactly the same error again.

Comment: @GeorginaDavenport Just because an answer is _wrong_ doesn't mean it's _not_ an answer. It just means it's a _wrong answer_.

Comment: I really don't see why an answer being a total failure written by somebody who hasn't bothered to think about it isn't something that means anything. Does that mean anybody is free to spam SO with random junk answers to questions even when they haven't got a clue what they're talking about, or whether the answer works, or is relevant to the problem?

Comment: @GeorginaDavenport *"who hasn't bothered to think about it"* - According to whom? you? For all you know they've put genuine thought into the answer and genuinely think it's going to help. And considering the user has answered 2000 questions and has a gold badge and amassed over 25k rep, it's pretty obvious that's the case. They intended it to be helpful answer, if you fail to see that then that's on you. It _is_ an answer, even if it's wrong.

Comment: No. I don't care how many other answers they've given which were satisfactory. He may have thought about others, but not this one. He claimed the correctness of his solution was clear. It wasn't at all clear. He *assumed* he knew what the answer was and assumed "ispcbin" was missing a backslash because, as I said right from the beginning, that's what you *might* think, if you just took a stab in the dark. If I wanted to take a wild stab in the dark I wouldn't have bothered posting the question. I can make random guesses myself. The point of asking is I wanted something better than guesswork.

Comment: This is frankly just characteristic of Stack Overflow: Far too many people having a crack who don't know what the answer is. So far absolutely none of the responses to this have been helpful.

Comment: Did you try reading the [documentation](https://ispc.github.io/ispc.html#using-the-ispc-compiler) (you know the one that clearly states the command is just `ispc` and that [gives](https://ispc.github.io/downloads.html) the `ispc.exe` file in the `bin` folder as the answer suggests.)

Comment: Right.... so you don't know what you're talking about either? You just fancy having a wild stab in the dark too? I have no trouble executing ispc. I know where the executable is. The problem is NOT being unable to find the ispc.exe and the build process is NOT looking for it. If you don't know the answer don't waste my time pretending you know better. It's just wasting your time and mine.

Comment: Yet you've failed to put any of your MSBuild configuration details into your question..., so what do you expect people to say?

Comment: Maybe if somebody thought that was a step towards a solution they should have asked that sometime in the last 18 hours?

Comment: @GeorginaDavenport that's already a prerequisite when you ask. We have an entire help center page dedicated to this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - some effort is expected from you before you ask, and being able to reproduce the issue is _critical_ if you want an answer

Answer (score 5):

Despite SE's maxim that "standard flags should be used whenever possible," I prefer a custom flag for these sorts of things.

Cast a custom flag with the description "flippant, inaccurate, incorrect and generally unhelpful answer" and see what happens.  Just don't expect moderators to curate technical content; it's not their job to determine whether an answer is "good" or not.

Comment: I agree with you there and you're right in point out that mods don't judge on technical correctness of the answer, so why do you suggest to write "inaccurate" and "incorrect" into the flag description, then this won't (and shouldn't) be part of a mods judgement?

Comment: Those were the words that the OP used.